# Interfaces are not passed by reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, pointers, reference

I need to change at runtime the implementation of an interface. This interface is referenced by many classes.

Here is my test case, which is not working as i was expecting. (changing the reference of the interface doesn't seems to update in all the places where its used)

Here is the example:

```
// interface to change at runtime
interface IDiet
{
    void Eat();
}

class CarnivoreDiet : IDiet
{
    public void Eat()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Eat chicken");
    }
}

class HerbivoreDiet : IDiet
{
    public void Eat()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Eat spinach");
    }
}

class Human : IDiet
{
    private readonly IDiet _diet;
    public Human(IDiet diet)
    {
        _diet = diet;
    }

    public void Eat()
    {
        _diet.Eat();
    }
}

void Main()
{
    IDiet diet = new CarnivoreDiet();
    Human human = new Human(diet);
    human.Eat();
    // outputs "Eat chicken"

    diet = new HerbivoreDiet();
    human.Eat();
    // still outputs "Eat chicken" even if i changed the reference of IDiet interface
}
```

Why is `IDiet` interface not updating inside `Human` instance?

PS: the `IDiet` interface is used in many classes, so adding a method like `SetDiet(IDiet diet)` won't be a solution.

Comment: What do you expect, and what behavior do you observe?  What do you mean by "not updating"?  The reference is read only; once you set it, the reference should be immutable.

Comment: Because Human has a copy of the reference (`_diet`) and you are modifying another copy of the reference (`diet`)

Comment: @Rahul this is essentially constructor injection.  I don't think IoC or DI changes anything.

Comment: Interfaces are irrelevant here - I think you fundamentally need to revisit how C# works. In particular, you seem to expect the `human._diet` field to be linked to the `diet` local variable. It's not - the value of `diet` was copied into the `diet` parameter which was then copied to the `_diet` field. Later changes to the `diet` local variable are irrelevant.

Comment: You might want to read http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html

Comment: OK, i understand the very stupid mistake i have made!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already implemented one facade, why not implement a second one:

```
class ChangableDiet : IDiet
{
    private IDiet _diet;
    public ChangableDiet (IDiet diet)
    {
        _diet = diet;
    }

    public Diet Diet { get { return _diet;} set { _diet = value; } }

    public void Eat()
    {
        _diet.Eat();
    }
}
```

Construct one of these and pass *it* to the `Human` constructor.

```
void Main()
{
    IDiet diet = new CarnivoreDiet();
    var changable = new ChangableDiet(diet)
    Human human = new Human(changable );
    human.Eat();
    // outputs "Eat chicken"

    changable.Diet = new HerbivoreDiet();
    human.Eat();
    // outputs "Eat spinach"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

When you pass your object reference by this code:

```
Human human = new Human(diet);
```

The reference (address of the object) is copied to its parameter:

```
public Human(IDiet diet)
{
        _diet = diet;
}
```

They are **3 different blocks of memory** containing the same reference to the object: your original `diet`, the parameter variable (`diet`) and your class property (`_diet`).

So when you execute your code:

```
diet = new HerbivoreDiet();
```

This memory block now contains reference to the new object (`HerbivoreDiet`), but the one inside the `Human` still references the old object.

Comment: And the parameter is copied to a field :-) Three different blocks of memory, of which one has a very limited duration (the parameter)

Comment: @xanatos: yes, I missed that. That was a mistake, but that's main the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

`diet` is a local variable, it's value being a pointer (address) to the actual object in memory.

if you go `diet.SomeProperty = "foo"`, you change the object in memory, which is reflected everywhere.

If you say `diet = new Diet()` you overwrite the local variable `diet` with a new pointer to another object.

The `Human` reference is unchanged because the pointer was passed by value. The object they point to was the same (until you overwrite diet), but the pointers were copies of each other.

You should make diet a accessible, non read only property and change it. Or create a new human.

Answer (score 1):

To the question: Why is `IDiet` interface not updating inside `Human` instance?

Simply because your interface reference is **passed by value** it means the reference you hold inside the `Human` class is a copy pointing at the same `IDiet`

Later by doing

```
diet = new HerbivoreDiet();
```

you just change the reference outside the `Human` class which still hold is own copy so there is no chance to change its reference.

Here is a solution you can implement:

```
public interface IProvider<T>
{
  public T Current {get; set;}
}

public class DietProvider : IProvider<IDiet>
{
  public IDiet Current {get; set;}
}

class Human : IDiet
{
  private readonly IProvider<IDiet> _dietProvider;

  public Human(IProvider<IDiet> dietProvider)
  {
    _dietProvider = dietProvider;
  }

  public void Eat()
  {
    _dietProvider.Current.Eat();
  }
}

void Main()
{
  IProvider<IDiet> dietProvider= new DietProvider { Current = new CarnivoreDiet()};
  Human human = new Human(dietProvider);
  human.Eat();
  // outputs "Eat chicken"

  dietProvider.Current = new HerbivoreDiet();
  human.Eat();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with interfaces.
What your code does is pass a variable into the class constructor by value, although the value is a reference to an instance. You then copy this value to a member of the instance of the newly created object. Then when you change the value in the variable that was initially used to hold the value it has no effect on the internal member in the instance of your class.

It would be exactly the same with `int`s. Consider this sample:

```
class MyClass {
   private int mInt;
   public MyClass(int theInt) {
      mInt = theInt;
   }

   public int GetTheInt() { return mInt; }
}

void Main()
{
   int anInt = 5;
   MyClass MyInstance(anInt);
   anInt = 10;
   if(MyInstance.GetTheInt() == anInt)
      // Will never happen
   ;
}
```